# Is it possible to rename & move a MultiBit wallet

Tags: wallet, multibit

I would like to reorganise a wallet I created with MultiBit. It seems to be composed of the XYZ.wallet file, plus a XYZ.info file and a XYZ-data folder. Can those be freely moved around into another directory? Can I rename the XYZ-part of these 3 items without causing MultiBit any problem?

Thanks for any advice and many greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be. But you will want to close MultiBit first, and then when you open MultiBit again you will need to tell it where you moved your wallet using File->Open Wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You can move them all together but do not rename them.

The data folder contains a whole load of backups which also use the wallet name (XYZ) in your example.

Comment: Combined with the above, it also worked fine :-) Thanks! After renaming and moving these additional files were regenerated correctly.